# spl-token 2.2.0 at solana 1.13.5 getting multisig error: Client(PresignerError(VerificationFailure))

Tags: spl-token, solana-cli, spl-token-program, multisig, blockhash

I've been using spl-token multisig for quite a while, but recently it stopped working and I'm getting this error:

```
Client(PresignerError(VerificationFailure))
```

We checked everything 10 times, rotated BLOCKHASH owners, but still no success, maybe someone noticed that too?

```
(all members ran this echo and got same results, all spl-token, solana cli versions are the same 2.2.0 and 1.13.5)

echo $TOKEN_ADDRESS $TOKEN_ACCOUNT $PKM $PK1 $PK2 $BLOCKHASH $FEE $NONCE_ACCOUNT
E5ndSkaB17Dm7CsD22dvcjfrYSDLCxFcMd6z8ddCk5wp 88DiZe8HKzupoVozYvHYjcnxWdEG53xxhTzBLUEndz3L 5MogdgJwD5EHmVCXHHa4TFoj8p1PoCaK9PQ9qgfrRsPC 58HsLURgpJCWWNX1Nsayf2cPNQu4q1ThTjGRNkPNztNV 3bqTcsJPHxR59uTkBExjVS3Ytq1SkA4rQvHmAQL3DZVp DMAj6eBFcvjwZS4hZStjdNdoc4xM71caAKG79VefBR8X 3n594wQbTLY1yyZ6rgXn6avJNHeGCUiUaqPZR7ocUJXC 5ArZh4GKmZ8iGmrLc8oXBR6bDTjg7V2KwxUfoz2yfa4o

spl-token transfer $TOKEN_ADDRESS 150000 $TOKEN_ACCOUNT \
    --owner $PKM \
    --multisig-signer $PK1 \
    --multisig-signer $PK2 \
    --blockhash $BLOCKHASH \
    --fee-payer $FEE \
    --nonce $NONCE_ACCOUNT \
    --nonce-authority $FEE \
    --signer $PK1=2W8xg5HUVVXrqJeB1T6yFnFeyPCJv4jc7wysuzrzZuB8rmJuLq6bQsvUzSzy7cc6pbGSMpEkNTKsXVzD3kmmVstE \
    --signer $PK2=FnVL6DFTe8jCGymGRfaR5bs6nJBKTr6usRjakq3RGbWZRjaYuvAtayqPPiXXp7REirZcYZvdqR9oSMj354K8K2f \
    --signer $FEE=JyBB7Sn73G3xJAzY6dsYAoJ5crV2D19d5e8McuYDHCF5hJdh9iBXKKcvAmJsgFrhKgmhUERUVAdUfXgxg5dvWtU
```

Comment: What changed between when it stopped working and now?

Comment: The problem rn is that CLI is trying to use the owner as a signer which doesn't make sense bcs it's a multisig PDA, the actual program doesn't require it so be a signer.

It was all working OK before, but maybe in recent solana upgrades they broke something in software of solana or spl-token cli

Comment: I'd try and work out what version it worked on, then test each upggade looking at the release notes. "library X version 1.2.3 breaks when I run doThing()" is a good bug report.

Comment: Can you provide the command and args that reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1):

downgrading to the last stable version of the cli works - v1.13.7 seems to work